# Exception when writing to an initialized 2D array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have this code, where I save a 2D JSONArray to a java 2D array.

```
JSONArray mapatest = mapObject.getJSONArray("map");
String[][] innerArray = new String[0][];

for(int t = 0; t < mapatest.length(); t++){
    JSONArray innerArrayObj = mapatest.getJSONArray(t);
    Log.e("TEST: ","PRUEBA");

    innerArray[t] = new String[innerArrayObj.length()];

    for(int k = 0; k < innerArrayObj.length(); t++){
        innerArray[t][k] = innerArrayObj.getString(k);
    }
}

mapa.setMapa(innerArray);
```

But when I run the app, it throws this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

I don't know where's the problem, the array is initialized.

Comment: Check if `innerArrayObj.length() != 0`

Comment: `String[][] innerArray = new String[0][];` creates an array of outer size `0`, therefore the array cannot hold any data. Thus if you try to access the array with any index you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Initializing isn't quite the whole story. Have you debugged your code to see what element you're trying to access when the exception occurs? Have you also checked to see that the initialized array is the size you expect?

Comment: I think you should change `innerArrayObj.getString(k);` to `innerArrayObj.getJSONObject(k).getString("jsonattr");`

Comment: So you "Checked already." And?? What did you find?

Comment: I found that the app throws the exception when I try to write in the array. If I change this: String[][] innerArray = new String[10][]; I get this exception: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared

```
String[][] innerArray = new String[0][];
```

This means that the outer dimension of `innerArray` is of size `0`. Keep in mind that an array of size `n` can be accessed with the indices `0`, `1`, ..., `n-1`. This implies that an array of size `0` cannot hold any data (but you can create it). As soon as you try to access `innerArray` with some index, like

```
innerArray[t] = new String[innerArrayObj.length()];
```

you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To solve this problem, you have to initialize the outer dimension of `innerArray` propperly (by glimpsing at your code I would say`String[][] innerArray = new String[mapatest.length()][];` should do it).

Comment: I understand this, but after that change, now I have the same exception in line: innerArray[t][k] = innerArrayObj.getString(k);

Comment: Look at this loop: `for(int k = 0; k < innerArrayObj.length(); t++)`. I am pretty sure the problem is within this line :-) I leave it to you to find and fix it.